# How to apply css of window in window.open()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

How to Apply Window form look in popup window created by Window.open() .

Thanks 
kamal

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much control over the look of a web browser window. You can, however, do some basic tricks like  setting hight and width, hide the address bar, change the color of the scroll, but not much.